# Getting same value for progress bar angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, progress-bar

Getting same value for progress bar angular.I need different values for each and every rows.

[image]

The below is my code and i used that private number in the html part.I can't able to give getRandomNumber() method to the

This raises some errors at the console.

```
export class UserlistComponent implements OnInit {



users: Observable<User[]>;
 // private number: number = this.getRandomNumber();

  constructor(private _service: NgserviceService, private _route: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadData();
  }

  getRandomNumber(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(100)+1);
  }

  get number() {
    return getRandomNumber();
  }

  reloadData() {
    this.users = this._service.getUserList().pipe(
      map(arrayUsers => arrayUsers.map(arrayUser => ({
        id: arrayUser[0],
        email: arrayUser[1],
        firstname: arrayUser[2],
        lastname: arrayUser[3],
      })))
    );
  }
}
```

**Html code:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goToAddUser()">Add User</button>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h2>User List</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>Progress</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of users | async">
        <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        <td>
          <button (click)="goToEditUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
          <button (click)="deleteUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 10px">Delete</button>
          <button (click)="goToViewUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 10px">Details</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-progress-bar [value]="number" style="margin-right: 300px" [bufferValue]="number+1"
                            [appProgressBarColor]="number"></mat-progress-bar>
          {{ number }}%
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code is my html code.i have used number here and i can't use getRandomNumber() at the html code also.Please Help me with the issue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please improve your description by explaining what behavior you would like to achieve. What should the progress bars indicate? Please edit your post and also show us some of your code so that we can get an idea of your intentions.

Comment: Ok, thank you for updating your question. It is easy to solve your problem now.
Follow my updated answer below to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through your users correctly with *ngFor
The problem is that you call number=getRandomNumber() only once, and use the same number everywhere else.

You might want to do:

```
[value]=getRandomNumber()

or you use a getter in your ts-code:
get number {
  return getRandomNumber()
}
Then you can use [value]=number in your html-code
```

I think this should fix your problem.

Comment: I used getRandomNumber() at the mat-progress-bar is raises expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror at the console and gives me wrong values

Comment: I updated my answer. Feel free to accept it if it hepls you or ask another question if it doesnt

Comment: I have used your solution and i got expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror and you can see that in the picture.please help me to solve the issue. @Chrissi Grilus

Comment: Yes, here you have a similar issue I think:
you provide "number" to both [value] as well as [appProgressBarColor]. This getter-method will return getRandomNumber() each time you call it. So it will be a different color each time. You can see this in that the bar has not the color it should have to the progress value of the bar.
Angular checks if "number" which you give to the same component twice is the same, which it is not => color != value. Angular saves you here.

You should either assign progress to your user-object in your map function in ngOnInit

Comment: You could also generate an array with the same length than you have users and than take the randomNumber from the same index than the user in the userArray. This would be a trick if you only want random numbers without making a property on your user object

Comment: Can you send me some code so that i can use it in my code @Chrissi Grilus - Thanks in advance.